# Determine stack usage of a posix pthread?

Tags: c++, pthreads, stack

How do I determine the current amount of stack space used by the current thread in a multi-threaded C++ program? I'm using POSIX pthreads.

I have a multi-threaded program where one of the stacks is blowing up, but I can't figure out which one. So I'm interested in having each thread report to a log file the current stack usage, which should be the difference between that thread's start of the stack and the current stack pointer. I know how to do this in assembly language but I'm looking for a portable approach using a `pthreads` call or something similar.

Thanks.

Comment: Stack space is reserved per thread, not just used. I.e. What problem are you trying to *solve*? Are you trying to stop code from running amok when it approaches the limited stack reserve you no-doubt set with `pthread_attr_setstack()` ?

Comment: I expanded the question. `pthread_attr_setstack` sets the stack size for new threads that are created. I want to know the current amount of stack space used.

Comment: Given the confines of your problem, the address of a local scope variable compared to that of a local at the top of your thread-proc would probably suffice. Not even *close* to portable, but it just might show the problem. Is the stack hit due to deep *recursion* (thus mondo activation frames) or really big fixed arrays? Regarding portable, however, I've no such knowledge such a mechanism even exists, but its been awhile since I was in pthreads-land.

Comment: I just finished a 12-hour run (with 64 threads!) and found that the problem is not deep recursion. We're doing more testing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a multi-threaded program where one of the stacks is blowing up, but I can't figure out which one.

Let the program crash and leave a `core` file. Load that `core` into a debugger, and *it will tell you right away* which thread crashed.

> The thread that crashed is not necessarily the one with the overflow.

It's true that there are scenarios where one thread overflows its stack, but another thread crashes because of it.

However, such scenarios are *exceedingly* rare (at least for non-user allocated thread stacks -- the pthread library will normally provide a stack guard page(s) to protect agains this). I can only think of one such scenario, and it's very unlikely in practice.

> I'm looking for a portable approach using a pthreads call or something similar.

There is no *portable* way to achieve what you want. On Linux, you could use `pthread_getattr_np` and `pthread_attr_getstack` to find boundaries of the current thread stack, and easily compute current stack use from there.

Comment: The thread that crashed is not necessarily the one with the overflow.